# How to print a vector line by line without the position numbers

Tags: r

how I can get straight line of hotel names without 1,2,3... in the first row. how can I do it?. I tried data.frame and list functions but failed. Thank you

[image]

Comment: anything you tried yourself?

Comment: what do you mena by "without the number"? Also use dput instead of a picture.

Comment: Is your goal printing to the console, writing to a file or something else?

Comment: df <- read.table(text=' Bilderberg Parkhotel Rotterdam#124547#4#3.7#83#0.5 miles to City centre#
NH Atlanta Rotterdam#208643#4#3.9#55#0.3 miles to City centre#
Nhow Rotterdam#439534#4#4.3#83#1.3 miles to City centre#
The Manhattan Hotel Rotterdam#173187#5#4.5#101#0.1 miles to City centre#
Mainport#427255#5#4.7#112#0.8 miles to City centre#', 
sep='#', comment.char='*')
 my goal is to convert this table to normal table and then to copy paste it to R. now they are all in characters so either I should to it manually or is there some shortcut? Thank you

Answer (score 7):

You could use `cat` instead.

Using the `letters` vector:

```
> cat(letters, sep='\n')
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
l
m
n

#<truncated>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use print with `row.names = FALSE`

```
print(foo, row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: I don't think this works for the `vector`.  Try `df <- data.frame(v1=c('Hotel Van Walsum', 'Bilderberge Parkhotel Rotterdam', 'NH Atlanta Rotterdam'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE); print(df$v1, row.names=FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
paste(df$V1, collapse=", ")
```

to get a comma separated list of hotel names.